# session_start() messes up PDF download through PHP in IE8

Tags: php, session, internet-explorer-8, http-headers, download

I use this code to send an PDF through PHP to the visitor ([link][1]):

```
session_start();

$fileName = '0-1.pdf';
$file = '../invoices/'. $fileName;
if (file_exists($file)) {
  $size = filesize($file);  
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $fileName .'"');
  header('Content-Length: '.$size);  
  header('Content-type: application/octetstream');
  #header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  echo file_get_contents($file);
}
```

It works well on Chrome, FF and IE 9 but fails on IE 8.

The reason it fails is

```
session_start();
```

If I leave it out, it will work in IE 8 as well.

Unfortunately I need the session. Since the whole reason for passing the PDF through PHP is to perform an authentication check. So I need the session ID to check if the current user is allowed to access the PDF.

Any ideas how to get the download to work in IE 8 with the headers session_start() sends?

Comment: No, no idea here—but be aware of the character encoding within your PDF-file. The Umlauts are misspelled, try to specify the to-be-used charset, when creating the PDF.

Comment: I already fixed the umlauts. Its just an old pdf I used here as an example.

Comment: Sounds like more an HTTP server issue than PHP... Which are you using? Apache? Nginx? PHP is CGI or a module? I suppose `session_start` perform cookie read/write, and you should examine the exact HTTP response sent by your server (check "Live HTTP Headers" or another Firefox extension to check the raw HTTP response)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution.

Aftter `session_start()` I have to set theese headers to get it to work with IE 8:

```
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("Pragma: public");
```

Strange behaviour... But it works now :-)